# Building a Navigation-Based project starting from a Window based project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

Just trying to wrap my head around how different project types are built and I must be missing something.

I'm trying to start with a window based application and just add a Navigation Controller so I understand how the different components work with the Window and App delegate.

Here's what I did:

- Created a Window based project
- In my app delegate.h I added
  `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;`

In my app delegate.m I added:

```
@synthesize navigationController;

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

- In the MainWindow.xib file I added a NavigationController below the
  Window
- Created a new UIViewController subclass (FirstView.h/m)
- Pointed the NavigationController's root view controller to FirstView

Builds clean, when I launch I get an all white screen.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - I had to create a new Referencing outlet and connect the Navigation Controller to the App Delegate in the .xib.

Answer (score 1):

Add this `[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];` You need to add the navigation controllers view to the window. Also make sure that the outlet for the navigation controller is connected. You will also need to add root view controller for the navigation controller

Comment: No change. And if this was the case - why doesnt this line appear when you create a new Navigation based project and view the AppDelegate.m?

Comment: You need to add root view controller for the navigation controller

Comment: I did - in the MainWindow.xib, selected Root View Controller inside of the Navigation Controller and selected my FirstView as the class...

Answer (score 1):

Actually barfoon..your navigation controller does not contains any `UIViewController`. First of all create new `UIViewController` and than add it to `UINavigationController`. `UINavigationController` is just like stack ,which handle each and every added UIViewController i.e traversing like back and forth.
Ex..

```
ToDoController *toDoObj = [[ToDoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToDoController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *toDoNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:toDoObj];
[self.window addSubview:toDoNav.view];
```

Comment: I don't want to `alloc` a `UINavigationController` - I've declared one in the header file, synthesized and assigned it in the implementation,  and it exists in the .xib

Comment: Did that - still a blank white screen

Comment: Actually barfoon you need to make link with delegate object(In yellow colored object in MainWindow.xib) and write this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :FirstView *fView = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fView];
 [self.navigationController setViewControllers:objects];
 [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];